# Onclick an element that changes the state of another element

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-handling, setstate

I'm trying to click on a sort icon that will trigger to change the order of a list.

To make it more simpler, let's say you have a button and another button and they are on separate divs from each other.

```
<div>
    //Button 1
    <button onclick={"some_click_handler"}>
</div>

<div>
    //Button 2
    <button>
        {this.state.someToggle ? true : false}
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a component which passes a callback to the button, this callback will update the state of the container which will in turn set the props of the list. This is very common in React and is the basis of how the compositional pattern works. If you need to share data between two components just put them in a container and lift the state to the parent component. These components are usually called containers and there is a bunch of documentation on it.

This is a good starting point: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Something like this...

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Don't forget to bind the handler to the correct context
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(sort) {
    this.setState({sort: sort});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      <List sort={this.state.sort} />
    )
  }
}
```